Power BI custom colum to calculate running total with conditions
I got a table with "Components" and quantity required "ToIssQty" among several orders, already sorted by component and required dates, need to add a column with running total at each chance on component

I used the following formula, however it just returns the total for each component, still need to show the incremental at each row
RunTotalToIss = 
CALCULATE (
    SUM (TBL_WorkOrder_Detail[ToIssQty]),
    FILTER(
        TBL_WorkOrder_Detail,
        TBL_WorkOrder_Detail[Component]
            = EARLIER(TBL_WorkOrder_Detail[Component])
    )
)



Can you try with this below measure-
RunTotalToIss = 

var this_row_component = min(TBL_WorkOrder_Detail[Component])
var this_row_releasedDate = min(TBL_WorkOrder_Detail[releasedDate])

return
CALCULATE (
    SUM (TBL_WorkOrder_Detail[ToIssQty]),
    FILTER(
        ALL(TBL_WorkOrder_Detail),
        TBL_WorkOrder_Detail[Component] = this_row_component
            && TBL_WorkOrder_Detail[releasedDate] < this_row_releasedDate
    )
)


maybe try something like this:
SUMX (
    FILTER (
        TBL_WorkOrder_Detail,
        TBL_WorkOrder_Detail[Component] = EARLIER ( TBL_WorkOrder_Detail[Component] )
            && TBL_WorkOrder_Detail[Date] <= EARLIER ( TBL_WorkOrder_Detail[Date] )
    ),
    TBL_WorkOrder_Detail[ToIssQty]
)


Reaaly appreciate it, This one worked perfectly; I've just added an index to use instead of date since some of them repeat on rows for the same component
RunTotalToIss = SUMX (
FILTER (
TBL_WorkOrder_Detail,
TBL_WorkOrder_Detail[Component] = EARLIER ( TBL_WorkOrder_Detail[Component] )
&& TBL_WorkOrder_Detail[Index] <= EARLIER ( TBL_WorkOrder_Detail[Index] )
),
TBL_WorkOrder_Detail[ToIssQty]
)
